# CMAKE string options

Tags: cmake

How to specify string `option` in `CMakeLists.txt`? Syntax `option(OPT1 "Helpstring" ON)` works perfectly for boolean options but I would like to have few string options like `-march=` argument passed to `gcc`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Any user-settable variable can be defined with [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry):

```
set(OPT2 "Default" CACHE STRING "Helpstring")
```

so -march would be something like:

```
set(ARCH "" CACHE STRING "Architecture to tell gcc to optimize for (-march)")
```

Comment: Usage example: `mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake .. -DARCH=native`

Comment: Note that instead of ``STRING`` you may use the types ``PATH`` or ``FILEPATH``. Those provide a folder or file selection dialog in CMake-GUI.

Comment: Note that you need to provide "Helpstring" if you want it to show up in cmake-gui list.

Comment: This is not working